# htaccess screwed Ajax hash # mark

Tags: javascript, ajax, .htaccess, hash, slash

I have pretty much standard rule that's adding slash to the end of the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Ajax photo gallery is making some additions with hash # to the URL like `URL/#photoset_photo_empty_progress`. I can't understand what htaccess blocks or does to hash string. But it screws this and gallery stops to work.

My thoughts are maybe it needs here some magic with htaccess to avoid this rule to be apply to hash string.

Please give me a solution because I can't even understand what's going wrong there.

---

```
var ls = ls || {};

ls.photoset =( function ($) {

    this.idLast=0;
    this.isLoading=false;
    this.swfu;

    this.initSwfUpload = function(opt) {
        opt=opt || {};
        opt.button_placeholder_id = 'photoset-start-upload';
        opt.post_params.ls_photoset_target_tmp = $.cookie('ls_photoset_target_tmp') ? $.cookie('ls_photoset_target_tmp') : 0;

        $(ls.swfupload).unbind('load').bind('load',function() {
            this.swfu = ls.swfupload.init(opt);

            $(this.swfu).bind('eUploadProgress',this.swfHandlerUploadProgress);
            $(this.swfu).bind('eFileDialogComplete',this.swfHandlerFileDialogComplete);
            $(this.swfu).bind('eUploadSuccess',this.swfHandlerUploadSuccess);
            $(this.swfu).bind('eUploadComplete',this.swfHandlerUploadComplete);
        }.bind(this));

        ls.swfupload.loadSwf();
    }

    this.swfHandlerUploadProgress = function(e, file, bytesLoaded, percent) {
        $('#photoset_photo_empty_progress').text(file.name+': '+( percent==100 ? 'resize..' : percent +'%'));
    }

    this.swfHandlerFileDialogComplete = function(e, numFilesSelected, numFilesQueued) {
        if (numFilesQueued>0) {
            ls.photoset.addPhotoEmpty();
        }
    }

    this.swfHandlerUploadSuccess = function(e, file, serverData) {
        ls.photoset.addPhoto(jQuery.parseJSON(serverData));
    }

    this.swfHandlerUploadComplete = function(e, file, next) {
        if (next>0) {
            ls.photoset.addPhotoEmpty();
        }
    }

    this.addPhotoEmpty = function() {
        template = '<li id="photoset_photo_empty"><img src="'+DIR_STATIC_SKIN + '/images/loader.gif'+'" alt="image" style="margin-left: 35px;margin-top: 20px;" />'
                    +'<div id="photoset_photo_empty_progress" style="height: 60px;width: 350px;padding: 3px;border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;"></div><br /></li>';
        $('#swfu_images').append(template);
    }

    this.addPhoto = function(response) {
        $('#photoset_photo_empty').remove();
        if (!response.bStateError) {
            template = '<li id="photo_'+response.id+'"><img src="'+response.file+'" alt="image" />'
                        +'<textarea onBlur="ls.photoset.setPreviewDescription('+response.id+', this.value)"></textarea><br />'
                        +'<a href="javascript:ls.photoset.deletePhoto('+response.id+')" class="image-delete">'+ls.lang.get('topic_photoset_photo_delete')+'</a>'
                        +'<span id="photo_preview_state_'+response.id+'" class="photo-preview-state"><a href="javascript:ls.photoset.setPreview('+response.id+')" class="mark-as-preview">'+ls.lang.get('topic_photoset_mark_as_preview')+'</a></span></li>';
            $('#swfu_images').append(template);
            ls.msg.notice(response.sMsgTitle,response.sMsg);
        } else {
            ls.msg.error(response.sMsgTitle,response.sMsg);
        }
        ls.photoset.closeForm();
    }

    this.deletePhoto = function(id)
    {
        if (!confirm(ls.lang.get('topic_photoset_photo_delete_confirm'))) {return;}
        ls.ajax(aRouter['photoset']+'deleteimage', {'id':id}, function(response){
            if (!response.bStateError) {
                $('#photo_'+id).remove();
                ls.msg.notice(response.sMsgTitle,response.sMsg);
            } else {
                ls.msg.error(response.sMsgTitle,response.sMsg);
            }
        });
    }

    this.setPreview =function(id)
    {
        $('#topic_main_photo').val(id);

        $('.marked-as-preview').each(function (index, el) {
            $(el).removeClass('marked-as-preview');
            tmpId = $(el).attr('id').slice($(el).attr('id').lastIndexOf('_')+1);
            $('#photo_preview_state_'+tmpId).html('<a href="javascript:ls.photoset.setPreview('+tmpId+')" class="mark-as-preview">'+ls.lang.get('topic_photoset_mark_as_preview')+'</a>');
        });
        $('#photo_'+id).addClass('marked-as-preview');
        $('#photo_preview_state_'+id).html(ls.lang.get('topic_photoset_is_preview'));
    }

    this.setPreviewDescription = function(id, text)
    {
        ls.ajax(aRouter['photoset']+'setimagedescription', {'id':id, 'text':text},  function(result){
            if (!result.bStateError) {

            } else {
                ls.msg.error('Error','Please try again later');
            }
        }
        )
    }

    this.getMore = function(topic_id)
    {
        if (this.isLoading) return;
        this.isLoading=true;

        ls.ajax(aRouter['photoset']+'getmore', {'topic_id':topic_id, 'last_id':this.idLast}, function(result){
            this.isLoading=false;
            if (!result.bStateError) {
                if (result.photos) {
                    $.each(result.photos, function(index, photo) {
                        var image = '<li><a class="photoset-image" href="'+photo.path+'" rel="[photoset]" title="'+photo.description+'"><img src="'+photo.path_thumb+'" alt="'+photo.description+'" /></a></li>';
                        $('#topic-photo-images').append(image);
                        this.idLast=photo.id;
                        $('.photoset-image').unbind('click');
                        $('.photoset-image').prettyPhoto({
                            social_tools:'',
                            show_title: false,
                            slideshow:false,
                            deeplinking: false
                        });
                    }.bind(this));
                }
                if (!result.bHaveNext || !result.photos) {
                    $('#topic-photo-more').remove();
                }
            } else {
                ls.msg.error('Error','Please try again later');
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }

    this.upload = function()
    {
        ls.photoset.addPhotoEmpty();
        ls.ajaxSubmit(aRouter['photoset']+'upload/',$('#photoset-upload-form'),function(data){
            if (data.bStateError) {
                $('#photoset_photo_empty').remove();
                ls.msg.error(data.sMsgTitle,data.sMsg);
            } else {
                ls.photoset.addPhoto(data);
            }
        });
        ls.photoset.closeForm();
    }

    this.closeForm = function()
    {
        $('#photoset-upload-form').jqmHide();
    }

    this.showForm = function()
    {
        var $select = $('#photoset-start-upload');
        if ($select.length) {
            var pos = $select.offset();
            w = $select.outerWidth();
            h = $select.outerHeight();
            t = pos.top + h - 30  + 'px';
            l = pos.left - 15 + 'px';
            $('#photoset-upload-form').css({'top':t,'left':l});
        }
        $('#photoset-upload-form').show();
    }

    this.showMainPhoto = function(id) {
        $('#photoset-main-preview-'+id).css('width',$('#photoset-main-image-'+id).outerWidth());
        $('#photoset-photo-count-'+id).show();
        $('#photoset-photo-desc-'+id).show();
    }

    return this;
}).call(ls.photoset || {},jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ajax photo gallery is making some additions with hash # to the URL like `URL/#photoset_photo_empty_progress`. I can't understand what htaccess blocks or does to hash string. But it screws this and gallery stops to work.

The `#` is part of a [URL fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) which is used by the browser to determine how it should be handling the content. It's used for named anchors that tells the browser to scroll to a particular part of the page, as well as being used by javascript (on the browser/client). **The fragment is never sent to the server in a request**. The server never sees the fragment at all, it's specific to only the client.

If you send to a webserver the request: `http://myserver.com/index.php#site-map`, the only thing the server sees in the request is `GET /index.php HTTP/1.1`. No `#site-map`. Because of this, your redirect essentially removes the fragment that was placed there by javascript. There's no way around it via the server, since it has no clue if there is or isn't a fragment held by the browser.

Possible work-arounds:

1. Ensure that all of your links, including any link you generate, on your entire site has the trailing slash so you don't need to redirect.
2. Add some kind of javascript to include a trailing slash whenever the photo gallery AJAX calls are made
3. Modify your mod_rewrite redirect code so that it *does not* redirect AJAX calls for the photo gallery.

Comment: The one interesting thing is that I don't see anything with `#` in browser if with empty `.htaccess` file. But I looked in the script of gallery and found `#` signs there inside. Does it change situation to find an easier solution? Take a look at that script. I've updated the question with that.

Comment: @user1707424 "*Does it change situation to find an easier solution? Take a look at that script.*" No, you have those 3 work-arounds still. There isn't an easier solution. It doesn't matter what the script is. You can change the script to include a trailing slash, or change your redirect so it ignore AJAX requests. AJAX calls don't show up in the browser's address bar, since they're asynchronously done by javascript.

Comment: Good, lets clarify possible solutions. If I change the script. Should I change for example string with the hash `$('#photoset_photo_empty_progress').text(file.name+': '+( percent==100 ? 'resize..' : percent +'%'));` to the same but with slash at the end `…percent +'%'+'/'));`?

Comment: @user1707424 Sorry, I don't know much javascript and don't know what that code does. If it were up to me, I'd just change the rewrite rule to ignore redirecting AJAX calls because users never see AJAX requests anyways, so unless there's some functional necessity to adding a trailing slash, there's no reason to do so.

Comment: Could you please show an example how to change redirect for the same string as below. I'm in doubt how I can describe RewriteCond exclusion for the Ajax hash request.

Comment: @user1707424 it depends on what the requests actually look like (I have no idea what they are), you should be able to find them in your access logs.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Now I don't even understand how they look like. Where I could find access logs?